# symbolicatecrash doesn't work because mdfind finds nothing

Tags: xcode4.5, symbolicatecrash

Running Xcode 4.5.2 on OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.2)

I'm trying to symbolicate crash reports but the symbolicatecrash script always fails. I'm not actually interested in the app symbols. I want the system library symbols, but it can't even find those:

```
..fetching symbol file for UIKit--[undef] 
Searching []...-- NO MATCH
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == CD513A2F-22F5-3D69-8C3E-10F6FE48A63E"
@dsym_paths = (  )
@exec_names = (  )
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

UIKit.framework with that UUID does exist:

```
$ pwd
/Users/karl/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks
$ dwarfdump --uuid UIKit.framework/UIKit 
UUID: CD513A2F-22F5-3D69-8C3E-10F6FE48A63E (armv7) UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

However, mdfind refuses to see it:

```
$ mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == CD513A2F-22F5-3D69-8C3E-10F6FE48A63E"
$
```

Even searching using mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == *" doesn't give any results inside of the Library dir or any system library/framework; only dSYM files from apps that I've compiled are listed.

How do I fix mdfind so that it includes system libraries in its searches?